# laravel Event shouldbroadcast not working

Tags: laravel, events, redis, broadcast

I am trying to make a realtime socket.io app.

The redis connect is good,because I can do this in tinker and it works fine.

```
Redis::publish('test-channel','test-message');
```

but I want to use event to publish the message

app\Events\ChatMessage.php:

```
    namespace App\Events;

    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

    class ChatMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

        public $name;
        public $message;

        public function __construct($name,$message)
        {

          $this->name = $name;
          $this->message = $message;
        }

        public function broadcastOn()
        {

          return ['test-channel'];
          // return new Channel('test-channel');
        }
    }
```

in public function broadcastOn

i tried

```
           return ['test-channel'];
           return 'test-channel';
           return new Channel('test-channel');
```

all doesn't work.

i do this in tinker

```
event(new App\Events\ChatMessage('bear','banana'));
```

and laravel just return []

I know I can use listener to handle it with Redis::publish(),
but most of tutorial doesn't do it.

what else do I have to check?

Answer (score 3):

I found that even I fire the event, the message will be queued.

After I run

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

the client recive the message!

So I solve it by changing ShouldBroadcast to ShouldBroadcastNow, and it work!

Comment: I guess it's the problem of laravel version, mine is 5.6 now.

Comment: I just have this problem now, I'm using the latest version of Laravel 7. And I could only solve the problem with `ShouldBroadcastNow`. I'm using dokku on the production server. Locally everything works fine with `ShouldBroadcast`